# How does HTTP Basic Auth persist across pageviews?

Tags: authentication, http

I am familiar with the basic workings of HTTP Auth, but how does it keep track of authentication between page views? I see there is no cookie created when the initial authentication takes place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To quote the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on this:

> Because the BA header has to be sent with each HTTP request, the web browser needs to cache credentials for a reasonable period of time to avoid constantly prompting the user for their username and password.

So it seems your browser takes care of this for you.

Answer (score 4):

> A client SHOULD assume that all paths at or deeper than the depth of
>   the last symbolic element in the path field of the Request-URI also
>   are within the protection space specified by the Basic realm value of 
>   the current challenge. A client MAY preemptively send the
>   corresponding Authorization header with requests for resources in
>   that space without receipt of another challenge from the server.

Source: [RFC 2617: HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt)

So the client/browser should handle this in some way per realm.